# Foldy-Wouthuysen (FW) Transformation alternative derivation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, special-relativity, dirac-equation

In my lecture, when considering the FW representation of the Dirac Equation, for the unitary matrix the following form was given:

$U=U^\dagger=(c\beta +\frac{\lambda}{m}\vec\alpha \vec p)$  with $c=\sqrt{1-\frac{\lambda^2 \vec p^2}{m^2}}$ where $\lambda$ belongs to the real numbers.

At some point during the different identities used in the derivation, the following step was written:

$Ue\Phi U^\dagger=ce\Phi c + \frac{\lambda}{m}\beta(ce\Phi \vec\alpha \vec p -\vec\alpha \vec p e\Phi c) + \frac{\lambda^2}{m^2}\vec\alpha \vec p e\Phi\vec\alpha \vec p $.

For the 2nd term it is said that we use {$\vec\alpha,\beta$} $=-I$.

How does this helps us transform the 2nd component?

Comment: You probably want to use a notation that is more systematic about vectors/indices.  To take the most obvious example, in $\{\vec{\alpha},\beta\}=-I$, the left-hand side is a vector, but the right-hand side is a scalar.  (Moreover, the equation is just wrong; the correct relation is $\{\alpha_{j},\beta\}=0$.)